# Condicionales con datatime Python

Tags: python, datetime

Eh buscado por internet como usar condicionales con datetime pero no aparece absolutamente nada, lo que deseo es activar algo cuando sea la mañana del dia siguiente, osea, ejemplo cuando llegue a las 12:00 AM del otro dia se active, pero supongamos que las 12:00 del otro dia ya paso y son la 1 de la madrugada de todos modos la condidicional se activa porque llego el otro dia y son mas de las 12:00, pero esta condición solo se realiza una vez por dia, osea cada dia se activa esa condición una sola vez.

Ejemplo, cuando sea tal dia a tal ahora entonces que suceda esto.

```
if fecha1 <= fecha2:
```

Comment: ¿`datatime` o `datetime`? Además, tu pregunta parece algo amplia. Por favor edítala y provee más detalles.

Comment: Acabo de buscar en Google condicionales datetime python y si aparece mucha información al contrario de lo que tu dices.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @omargt8 Debiste colgar el link porque yo no logre encontrar nada.

Comment: @DiegoRamirez Eso es todo, no eh puesto el codigo porque realmente no se ni como empezar, no se como se forma una condicional que se active cuando llegue una fecha o una hora especifica.

Comment: @Comunidad Eso es todo, no eh puesto el codigo porque realmente no se ni como empezar, no se como se forma una condicional que se active cuando llegue una fecha o una hora especifica.

Comment: Quizas lo que estas buscando son los `hilos` o `threads` en python. espero te ayude. saludos.

Comment: No tengo idea de que son los hilos o threads de python, pero mire algo y no se que tienen que ver con el tiempo o la fecha, lo que ando buscando es una especie de condicional que se active cuando sea mañana una sola vez por dia.

Comment: Tiene que ser con codigo python? Porque tal y como lo cuentas, la orden cron de linux te seria muy util para programar la ejecución del proceso

Answer (score 0):

Aqui la solucion:

```
import datetime

fechaActual1 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
fechaAlarma = "2021-12-19 18:41:46.094624"

while fechaActual1 != fechaAlarma:
    fechaActual1 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(fechaActual1)
    if fechaActual1 == fechaAlarma:
        print("*Suena una alarma*")
```

Version input(incompleta)

```
import datetime

# fecha actual
fechaActual1 = str(datetime.datetime.now())

# Input
hora = input("Que hora desea colocar? ")
minuto = input("Que minuto desea colocar? ")
segundo = input("Que segundo desea colocar? ")

# Alarma str
Alarma = str("2021-12-18 " + hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo + "." + "000000")

while fechaActual1 != Alarma:
    fechaActual1 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(fechaActual1)
    if fechaActual1 == Alarma:
        print("*Suena una alarma*")
```

Comment: Tu codigo se acerca un poco a lo que busco, hice una mejora a mi explicación para que entiendas mas o menos, un resumen de lo que busco seria lo siguiente, si es el dia de mañana entonces ocurrira esto, pero solo lo hace una sola vez por dia.

Comment: @Musicofthemoment. Lo que entendi es que quieres hacer algoa si como una alarma no? que se active todos los dias a la hora predefinida no? creo saber como hacerlo.

Comment: Exacto, que se active a las 12:00 AM o despues de esta hora.